# How to retrieve single solr child document

Tags: solr, lucene

Hello I used solr block join and query expansion at the same time. The parent entity has several child documents. For example, an author has many articles. I use {!parent which="type:parent"} article_name &expand=true&expand.field=*root*&expand.q=*:* to retrieve author and its article at the same time. However, the result contain all documents of that author. How can I retrieve only one article which matches the search terms?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use fl with limit param，as：

> *,[child parentFilter=type:parent limit=1]

. then,you may get only 1 child document each parent.